# Aligning a centered div to have height 100%, and stretch between two other divs on any browser, opacity, and other questions

Tags: html, css

so, I have a couple questions. The site in question is here:

www.vutallindustries.com/penultimatum

What I am trying to do, is get the center box to stretch between the two divs already on the side, but also take up the full screen (just not go above the top margin I already have set), Currently, the DIV will stretch with text and resize as appropriate, but only if i put in that much text. Dont like to rely on text to do my job!

The other thing, is since people will be accessing this site from various mediums, it is important that things don't overlap when the screen is stretched or resolutions are different. I have played around with different floats and widths, but this is the best I could come up with.

Additionally, on the Gallery link, any idea how to insert those images as they are but not transparent? Id like to keep the middle div transparent, but not the screenshots. Thanks for all your help!

Any additional tips errors you might see, or coding optimizations you could find would be much appreciated as well!

Here is the Style sheet:

```
body {
background-color:#000000;
background-image:url(http://www.vutallindustries.com/websitefiles/welcomepage.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
color:#000000;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
/* Corp Logo */
.logo {
position: fixed;
height: 128px;
width: 128px;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
}
/* EVE Logo */
.logo2 {
position: absolute;
height: 128px;
width: 128px;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
}
/* Site Navigation menu */
.menu {
position: fixed;
width: 128px;
height: 100%;
left: 0px;
top: 128px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid black;
text-align:left;
opacity:0.6;
filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}
/* Official EVE news via RSS */
.news {
float:right;
width: 128px;
height: auto;
margin-top: 129px;
margin-right:0px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid black;
text-align:left;
opacity:0.6;
filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}
/* website content */
.content {
width: auto;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid black;
opacity:0.6;
filter:alpha(opacity=60);
}
/* centers website content */
div.centerbox-outer {
margin-top:129px;
margin-right:136px;
float: left;
position:fixed;
left:136px;
}
```

And here is the main index HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <title>Penultimatum</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link REL="StyleSheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="layout.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="http://www.vutallindustries.com/websitefiles/emblem.png" alt="Penultimatum">
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <p> <b> <a href="http://www.vutallindustries.com/penultimatum" target="_self">Home</a> </b>

        </p>
        <p> <b> <a href="http://www.vutallindustries.com/penultimatum/forum" target="_self">Forum</a> </b>

        </p>
        <p> <b> <a href="http://www.vutallindustries.com/penultimatum/gallery.html" target="_self">Gallery</a> </b>

        </p>
        <p> <b>Note: if anyone can figure out how to make the center box centered and scroll with, it would be much appreciated. </b>

        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="logo2">
        <img src="http://www.vutallindustries.com/websitefiles/evelogo.jpg" alt="Penultimatum">
    </div>
    <div class="news">
        <p>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://output42.rssinclude.com/output?type=js&amp;id=629071&amp;hash=623340dcbe5d6196e04dc473e9f193b0"></script>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="centerbox-outer">
        <div class="centerbox-inner">
            <div class="content">
            <p> <b>Welcome to the EVE Online corporation, Penultimatum! We are currently standing up offices, and this website is under construction. Check back in later for more details</b>
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then the gallery page is the same as the index, it just replaces the line about welcome to the EVE online corp with the following code:

```
<p>
                <center>
                <a href="http://www.vutallindustries.com/websitefiles/test.png">
                    <img src="http://www.vutallindustries.com/websitefiles/test.png" alt="Vutall's Character"
                    width="auto" height="150">
                    </a>
                </center>
                </p>
                <p>
                <center>
                Vutall's Character
                </center>
                </p>
```

Comment: TL;DR (Too many questions, too much code. Ask one question at a time and post only the relevant code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with the solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/yKVq4/5/

**Summary of Changes**

1. I cleaned up a lot of your code, because there were a lot of redundant things.
2. I added containers to the left and right side because this will prevent things like writing `position:fixed` and `width:128px` a bunch of times.
3. I found when I changed the positioning of `div.centerbox-outer` to relative, but kept `position:fixed` later on down the line, the code suddenly centered and now always spans the full length, no matter what. After some playing around with the code, it is the combination of the `right` and `left` `position` that is doing it.
4. Because I changed the alignment of the containers from `position:fixed;` to `float`, the result was a more responsive solution. It is quite crude, but it will get the job done.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

**Edit**

I have found that if I change the `div.centerbox-outer`'s positioning to `absolute`, then add a `margin-right` to the `.menu-container`, then there is a greater responsive design outlook

**Update**

I came up with a possible responsive design layout http://jsfiddle.net/yKVq4/42/

*Summary*

- Once the screen gets to less than 400 px, move the welcome banner to the top to keep it out of the way.
- Increase the menu size to 100% after it has shrunk past 300px and remove the float. Same with the other floated container. Also made the images responsive

*Other Changes*

- Added some simple styles to the menu, after changing it into a unordered list
- Added transitions
- Fixed the problem with the background not working, although now it is not fixed.

I changed this a lot. But it is because I like coding so much ;)

Comment: I'll have to take a better look at it when I have a bit more time, just about to head to bed, but from what I saw that looks much better Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: Just message me if there is anything else I can help with

Comment: Not to shabby. Will need to fiddle with it myself to get the icons on the left and right flush with the text boxes below them, but that is fixed by margin-top: -#px. Interesting with the contain boxes on the left and right, I never thought about that.

Comment: Thank you. It just seemed like a more practical solution. I'm not sure why the `img` has a margin below it. Because that isn't in the code anywhere

Comment: Did a bit of fiddling myself, and found a really elegant solution that shouldnt break things. Altered your @media code and added another div, plus added the image gallery esque code. Link to site here: http://www.vutallindustries.com/penultimatum/    and link to code: http://jsfiddle.net/76YCR/

Comment: I highly disagree with the concept of limiting screen size. That defeats the point of a responsive solution. Was there something wrong with my solution?

Comment: Was running into stacking on the gallery page where the images would overlap all at smaller screen size, as well as the middle text overlapping if adding a lot in there. . Yours was perfect until I putzed around with the gallery page and adding more text. Overlap cut wouldn't get rid of it either. Best I could come up with was display hide, but then I wondered if people would be askign why they couldnt see things, so I changed it to current.

Comment: Can you post my fiddle as a question and ask how to better enable responsive design, then I will answer that one for you.

Comment: Sure, no problem. One thing to keep in mind, while the website is intended to be viewable by all, the main audience would be the EVE online community, which has an in-game browser that people resize all the time to see their UI. Here is an example: http://e.dotlan.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/new-igb-03.jpg

Comment: Which makes even more reason to have a completely responsive solution. Don't forget to be specific in your question or you will get downvoted. Can you accept my answer too?

Comment: Will do. Also will make a comment in code that you helped me out. Credit where credit is due, after all.

Comment: Please upvote as well. I just like rep ;) I upvoted you as well

Comment: Can't upvote until I get 15 reputation. Here is the link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720513/looking-for-tips-on-responsive-design-on-website

Comment: Add the image gallery to the question

Comment: Alrighty, done as an edit on bottom of post. Kept your CSS the same, just added in the image coding to it.

Comment: I will work on it tomorrow. I need to do homeword ;) I'll come up with something good.

Comment: @ThomasStavlo I answered the question in case you hadn't noticed. I hope that was what you were looking for.